# How to install GRUB boot loader to boot into Windows OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I dual-booted my PC with Windows and Ubuntu OS. While installing I created different partition for boot-loader,Home and Root. On starting my PC I was again and again booted into Linux instead of windows so I just removed grub from the partition now after few months I somehow managed to boot into Linux but now as I start my PC I am booting into Linux and not getting a way to boot into windows os.
And I am unable to to install grub boot-loader because the boot partition is showing "Unallocated Space" .
So is there anyway through which I can again boot into Windows or a way to install boot-loader.

Comment: What is your objective, to dual boot or just boot Windows? Are Windows and Ubuntu on the same disk? If the answer to that is no then you can probably change your boot order in the BIOS/UEFI and boot the Windows disk first. Has this ever dual booted both from a grub menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)